# Update array inside object if it exists, otherwise push array to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If the object is currently in the array I want to update some value, and if it's not I want to add it to the array. This is the solution I have below, which I don't feel is the best/correct way to do it.

```
const handleAddToCart = product => {
  const newList = [...cart]
  if (!newList.includes(product)) {
    newList.push(product)
  } else {
    const productIndex = newList.findIndex((obj => obj._id === product._id))
    newList[productIndex].prop = "Some value"
  }
  setCart(newList)
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is there some unique identifier for each object? If not, then you will need to do a deep comparison of the objects.

Comment: Each object in the Array has a unique _id property.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be pretty careful here, as there are a few gotchas with object comparison and mutating the state (`[...cart]` is not sufficient in deep copying `cart`). You can update the state in a pure fashion as follows, although I would recommend something like Redux for complex state management.

```
const handleAddToCart = product => {
    const index = cart.findIndex(obj => obj._id === product._id)
    if (index === -1) {
        setCart(cart.concat(product))
    } else {
        setCart([
            ...cart.slice(0, index),
            Object.assign({}, product, { prop: "Some value" }),
            ...cart.slice(index + 1),
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleAddToCart = productToAdd => {
    const newList = [...cart];
    const existent = newList.find(product => product.id === productToAdd.id);
    if(existent) {
        existent.prop = "prop";
    } else {
        newList.push(productToAdd);
    }
    setCart(newList);
}
```

Comment: Would `existent.prop = productToAdd.prop;` be directly mutating the state? Also, I think you meant `push` instead of `add`.

Comment: @iz_ since we're passing new array to the `setCart()` it's enough to initiate re-rendering. And thanks for noticing `add` )

Comment: I'm not very familiar with React internals, but this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997 seems to suggest that you should avoid mutating state even if it does not cause any immediate problems.

Comment: @iz_ generally it's a good suggestion. But it depends on structure of component. And it's really applicable to redux reducers. I just answered the question of the topic.